# How to provide updates of published app on Google Play?

Tags: android

I have published my app on google play which uses database. Now what I want is provide the software updates without disturbing the existing database. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A software update should not harm your database. It persists from update to update.

Comment: thanks a lot. i will try and release the update hope everything works as intended :)